# Explain the formula for the size of an orbit...

Tags: group-theory

Explain the formula for the size of an orbit and show that this always is a divisor of the group order $|G|$. (You may use Lagrange's theorem!)

So I would like to know how i can go about answering this. I know there are a few question fairly similar to this but all answers involve using cosets, and proving bijections. I am not to sure whether i would need to do that or whether there is a simpler way?

Comment: Have you heard of the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem?  As a heads up, you will need bijections: it's about the only way to move relevant information from the group to the set the group acts upon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Size of orbit of $x$ divides the order of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951559/size-of-orbit-of-x-divides-the-order-of-g)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can easily find more about this basic and important point in any permutation book. But,let $G$ is a group which acts on the set $\Omega$ transitively. It means that $$\forall\omega_1,\omega_2\in\Omega; ~\exists g\in G,~~~\omega_1^g=\omega_2$$ Set $\Omega^*=\{G_{\omega}x\mid x\in G\}$ wherein $G_{\omega}$ is the stabilizer of $\omega\in\Omega$. In fact, you are considering the right coset of $G_{\omega}$ in the group. Define the following map: $$f:\Omega^*\to\Omega\\\ f(G_{\omega}x)=\omega^x$$ It can be easily verified that $f$ is well-defined and one-one function:
$$G_{\omega}x=G_{\omega}y\longleftrightarrow xy^{-1}\in G_{\omega}\longleftrightarrow\omega^{xy^{-1}}=\omega\longleftrightarrow \omega^x=\omega^y$$ it is onto also (Why?) Therefore, $$|\Omega|=|\Omega^*|=[G:G_{\omega}]$$ Now think that the action is not transitive. What will happen? Indeed, we should replace $|\Omega|$ by $|\omega^G|$ the orbit corresponding to $\omega$. In fact, $$|G|=|\omega^G||G_{\omega}|$$

Comment: $+1 \;\;\mathcal{Nice}\;\mathcal{Work}\;!$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks my $\mathcal{Dear}$. ---(--{@

Comment: $\Large \ddot\smile \;\heartsuit\;$