# Size of orbit of $x$ divides the order of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm having a bit of trouble "closing" this question (finishing it):

Suppose that $G$ acts on $X$ and let $x \in X$. Let stab($x$) = {$g$ | $gx = x$}. Show that the size of the orbit of $x$ divides the order of $G$. (Hint: LaGrange's Theorem and the fact that stab($x$) is a subgroup of $G$).

Here's what I got so far:

I'm thinking that the orbit of $x$ $\in$ stab($x$), which is a subgroup of $G$. But I have no basis for this line of logic, and am having some trouble figuring out what the orbit of $x$ is. I know that the orbit of $x$ is all the possible values that can be reached by the actions of $G$. So wouldn't that mean the orbit of $x$ is just all of $X$? Any help with this problem would be great. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Is the orbit of $x$ the order of stab($x$)? If so, how would I go about proving it?

Comment: The result to use here is the orbit stabilizer theorem.

Comment: We haven't learned that yet. I just looked it up, and I'm not quite sure if I understand it. What is the intuition behind the theorem?

Comment: Its an improvement of the obvious claim: "the less you fix, the bigger the orbit." It says those quantities are inversely proportional, as expected.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Funny but useful comment that captures the essence of the result.

Comment: So, according to the orbit-stabilizer theorem, the orbit of $x$ is everything in $G$ that's not in stab($x$), right? How would I actually find the orbit of $x$ in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The stabilizer subgroup consists of the elements of $G$ that fix $x$.  Any time you have a subgroup of a group, you can consider the cosets of that subgroup.  If $H$ is the stabilizer subgroup of $x$, what can you say about the action of the cosets on $x$? (Note: none of this requires $H$ to be normal, btw.)  For example, if $g \not \in H$, so that $gx \ne x$, what can you say about the action on $x$ of elements in the coset $gH$?  Well, I'll leave it to you to show this, but each element does the same thing (i.e., sends $x$ to the same point in the orbit.)

This allows us to establish a correspondence between the cosets of $H$ and elements of the orbit of $x$: $gH \mapsto gx$.  As a second exercise, you can show that this correspondence is bijective (i.e., the cardinality of $G/H$ coincides with that of the orbit $\mathcal{O}_x$.  Your desired result follows from the fact that $|G| = |G/H| \cdot |H|$.

Answer (score 2):

since $G$ act on $X$, by Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, we have
$$|Orb(x)|=|G: Stab_G(x)|.$$
Thus $|Orb(x)|=\frac{|G|}{|Stab(x)|}$. Clearly, $\frac{|G|}{|Stab(x)|} \mid |G|$. So $|Orb(x)| \mid |G|$.